# Add chart using code

Tags: wpf, charts, telerik

I try to add to my `WPF application` `Chart View` and want to use [this](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/populating-with-data/static-data) tutorial.
So after add this declaration in `XAML`:

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart x:Name="chart"/>
```

Add this code (the same like the exapmle)

```
RadCartesianChart chart = new RadCartesianChart();
    chart.HorizontalAxis = new CategoricalAxis();
    chart.VerticalAxis = new LinearAxis(){ Maximum = 100 };
    LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
    line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    line.StrokeThickness = 2;
    line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 20 });
    line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 40 });
    line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 35 });
    line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 40 });
    line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 30 });
    line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 50 });
    chart.Series.Add(line);
    this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(chart);
```

But in last line the word `LayoutRoot` is not recognized and i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the tutorial it assumes there is an object on the page called LayoutRoot.

You need to a grid or some other layout as the root element on the page for it to work. 
When you see the `this.` that is looking for members of the class your in. Members can either be defined in code behind, the .cs file, like so:

```
//outside of a method
public Grid LayoutRoot;

//Then somewhere in the constructor
LayoutRoot = new Grid()
```

Or in the .xmal like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
```

It will take what ever name is stated in the x:Name property and can then be refereed to in the code behind with `this.LayoutRoot`

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you show me code example ? i am new developer and i didn't understand what i should do

Comment: I can put the exact code because I don't know what else you have, but hopefully what I've added should help you understand.

Comment: That's fishy because i suppose to receive chart with several point ot it and i only can see my chart with the message that telerik wpf vertical Axis not set and telerik wpf Horizontal Axis not set although i have this in the code example, any suggestion ?

Comment: In the example all the bits with line.DataPoints.Add are adding dummy data. You need to replace that with your real data.

Comment: That's isn't dummy data, that's several difference value that i need to see on my chart but only received message that Horizontal and Vertical Axis is not set

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your .xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Loaded="LayoutRoot_Loaded" >
```

And in your 
  .cs

```
private void LayoutRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

 RadCartesianChart chart = new RadCartesianChart();
chart.HorizontalAxis = new CategoricalAxis();
chart.VerticalAxis = new LinearAxis(){ Maximum = 100 };
LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
line.StrokeThickness = 2;
line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 20 });
line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 40 });
line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 35 });
line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 40 });
line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 30 });
line.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = 50 });
chart.Series.Add(line);
this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(chart);
}
```